# How to get latitude and longitude of current location using google map api but without displaying the maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get only the latitude and longitude of my current location using google maps. But I dont want to display the map. Is it possible to do so? And how can I use only Internet without Gps to get my current location?

Comment: use the location manager?

Comment: Yep the location manager and a Broadcast receiver

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the location using a LocationManager, Google Maps actually utilizes similar functionality to get the location before drawing it (and the map) for you. You may certainly only use your network provider for GPS locations, you should look into differences between FINE and COARSE locations (and their permissions). I would start posting links, but there are tons. Just start googling for LocationManager and Network GPS on Android. Just for fun though, here is the first link I found (seems to be pretty solid).

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/